# Trying to make a login with Spring

Tags: java, html, spring, authentication

So we are making a login for our project. The problem we have is that we only get null in our parameters and not the actual value we entered. Anybody know why?

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/login",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String logIn(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {

 //Random code here

 return "redirect:/general/index.html";

}
```

View:

```
<form:form id="header_login_form" method="POST"  ModelAttribute="user" action="/ProjectTeamF-1.0/user/login.html">
    <input path="username"class="input" placeholder="Email" />
    <input path="password" class="input" placeholder="Password" />
    <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"> Aangemeld blijven</label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Aanmelden</button>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the tag `<form:input>` instead of `<input>` in order for Spring to bind the `user` ModelAttribute. And replace `ModelAttribute` by `commandName`:

```
<form:form id="header_login_form" method="POST"  commandName="user" action="/ProjectTeamF-1.0/user/login.html">
    <form:input path="username"class="input" placeholder="Email" />
    <form:input path="password" class="input" placeholder="Password" />
    <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"> Aangemeld blijven</label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Aanmelden</button>
</form:form>
```